# CSS grid create not equal grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

started using CSS grid instead of boostrap, and im having some issue to get it right.

i want to create a grid layout that have 4fr, and 8fr columns (just like boostrap 8 and 4 columns)
and when the divs inside the grid of 4r gets fill its the divs go to a second row just like flex-wrap:wrap.

BUT Its not work its only push it inline one after another, and ignoring the grid boundaries

```css
.home {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:  4fr 8fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="col-8">

  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <mat-button-toggle-group class="side-menu-button">
      <mat-button-toggle>test </mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle>test</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle>test</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle>test</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle>test</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle>test</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle>test</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle>test</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

i even tried changing it to

```
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto-fill, 4fr 8fr);
```

Comment: as a side note, bootstrap is using flexbox which more suitable here

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes but bootstrap come with a bunch of staff i dont need. can i import only the grid layout?

Comment: This looks like normal behaviour to me? You have one row with 2 columns. And you put all the "test" values in the 8 column. So they will stay there? It is not ignoring the boundaries?

Comment: I never said you should use bootstrap. I said bootstrap is using flexbox so what you want is more suitable for flexbox

Comment: @TemaniAfif So what should i use if not boostrap? only flexbox? I thought its better to get some boundaries  and then inside using flexbox. its a large project with many buttons and screens, and need to be responsive as well.What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just wanting to use the grid to have items wrap inside of a div, what you're doing should basically work. Don't forget to tell `.col-8` and `.col-4` where they belong inside of the grid you've set up, and set the children you want to wrap to `inline-block`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.home {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.col-8 {
  grid-area: 1/1/1/9;
}

.col-4 {
  grid-area: 1/9/1/13;
}

.bluebox,
.blackbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}

.bluebox {
  background-color: blue;
}

.blackbox {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason I set up 12 columns instead of one that's 8fr and one that's 4fr is because I'm unclear about whether you're wanting a 12 column usable system like bootstrap (which is the way I implemented it), or literally only two columns. Either way should function for what you are describing in your question, but 12 separate columns is arguably more extensible later-on.

Here's a pen that contains the above code:
https://codepen.io/grantnoe/pen/MdOQOv

`grid-area` is what I used to set the location of .home's children. The format is as follows:

`grid-area: <row-start> / <column-start> / <row-end> / <column-end>;`

**The only caveat** is that you've nested the children you're wanting to wrap inside of secondary element `<mat-button-toggle-group>`. Consider adjusting the width of that element to 100% to fill the grid's child `.col-4`.